# haskell and string length

Tags: haskell

i'm newbie in haskell, and i have question:
i write code:

```
word_list = ["list", "lol", "wordword"]
check str = if head str == 'l' then tail str else str
average wl = (length $ concat $ map check wl) `div` length wl
```

this code must delete first "l" symbol in every word in word list, concat recieved words, get length of result string and div on words count.

so in this code i must recieve:
13 / 3 = 4,333...  ("listlolwordword" = 15, "istolwordword" = 13)
but i recieve just 4.

`average :: [[Char]] -> Float` don't work, i recieve error. where my mistake?
ps. sorry my english, please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `length` function returns an `Int`, and the `div` function performs integer division, in other words, it drops the fractional part. If you want a `Float` result, you need to first convert the result of `length` to a `Float`, then use `(/)` for division instead:

```
word_list = ["list", "lol", "wordword"]
check str = if head str == 'l' then tail str else str
average wl = fromIntegral (length $ concat $ map check wl) / fromIntegral (length wl)
```

While I'm at it, you should consider using pattern matching in `check` instead, e.g.:

```
check ('l':str) = str
check str = str
```

This style is both more readable and less likely to have mistakes--for example, your version will fail if given an empty string.

Comment: wow. thanks you very much!
  about pattern matching: it amazing! i like hasskel more much every day :)

Comment: @user: Note that there's also concatMap so you don't have to do `concat $ map`.

Comment: and I would note that a more clear approach is probably `sum $ map (length . check) wl` (although fusion likely renders this unimportant)